# Dining savages problem - Semaphores and Mutexes

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, semaphore

I've encountered the dining savages problem and solution, but I don't seem to understad how the solution is handling the situation when a savage tries to eat from the pot while it's still empty.
The problem and solution from *the little book of semaphores*:

> A tribe of savages eats communal dinners from a large pot that can
> hold M servings of stewed missionary. When a savage wants to eat, he
> helps himself from the pot, unless it is empty. If the pot is empty,
> the savage wakes up the cook and then waits until the cook has
> refilled the pot.
> Any number of savage threads run the following Unsynchronized savage code:

```
while True :
    getServingFromPot()
    eat()
```

> And one cook thread runs this Unsynchronized cook code:

```
while True:
    putServingsInPot(M)
```

The synchronization constraints are:

> - Savages cannot invoke getServingFromPot if the pot is empty.
> - The cook can invoke putServingsInPot only if the pot is empty.
>
> Puzzle: Add code for the savages and the cook that satisfies the
> synchronization

Solution (cook):

```
while True:
    emptyPot.wait()
    putServingsInPot(M)
    fullPot.signal()
```

Solution (savages):

```
while True:
    mutex.wait()
    if servings == 0:
        emptyPot.signal ()
        fullPot.wait ()
        servings = M
    servings -= 1
    getServingFromPot ()
    mutex.signal()

    eat()
```

My question - when we first reach `servings = 0`, after M savages ate form the pot, we get to `emptyPot.signal()` and then `fullPot.wait()` - Both semaphores; then, from my point of view there might be a corner case where we may get to `getServingsFromPot` before the cook has the chance to get context and fill the pot. Am I missing something?

Comment: A savage is holding the mutex when they are about to eat, because the code passes through `mutex.wait()`. So, if the pot is empty and they ask the cook to refill it and wait for that refilling, no other savage will access the pot and eat from it because they cannot get the mutex. So the pot will have the M servings that the cook put into it when this savage goes to eat. What “corner case” do you envision where the pot is not full after the savage waited for it to be full?

Comment: Why do you say they wait for the cook to fill it?My understanding is the  the fullPot.wait () is signalling down the semaphore, not waiting as in mutex

Comment: You have not provided any documentation about what these things do. Somebody could name a routine anything; a routine named 'SendPaperToTokyo` might actually calculate the minimum mass needed for a nova, but my expectation is that something called `fullPot.wait` waits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `signal` and `wait` are the usual V and P semaphore operations.

I think you might be missing the point of each semaphore.

- `emptyPot`: cook will not fill the pot unless a savage has signaled that the pot it empty;
- `fullPot`: the savage who signaled that the pot is empty will not get a serving unless the cook has signaled that the pot is full;
- `mutex`: a savage who wants to eat will not proceed unless another savage has signaled that they're done serving themselves.

Therefore:

- multiple savages can be eating at the same time;
- no two savages will try to serve themselves at the same time;
- a savage will not try to serve themselves if the pot is empty;
- **after waking up the cook, a savage will not try to serve themselves unless the pot is full**.

Thus, there can be no race condition. Due to calling `fullPot.wait()`, a savage **cannot** get to `getServingsFromPot` until the cook has woken up, filled the pot and called `fullPot.signal()`.